# executing a Node Script with the "NodeJS Portable" .exe

Tags: node.js

How to exec a Node Script with the normal "NodeJS Portable" .exe?

Got answered somewhere else.

**1.** Go into:
NodeJS Portable\App

**2.** Open "Server.cmd"

**3.** Write the path to your Script

```
cd ../account/example/
```

**4.** Write the Node Command

```
node test.js
```

**5.** Now just Start the NodeJsPortable.exe

**Full Server.cmd Example**

```
@echo off

title Steam - Test BOT

cls
echo.
echo Node
node --version
echo.
cd ../account/example/
node test.js
cmd /k
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: ohhh the second i delete the queston some one commented but no one cared before nice :)